# Is there a way to save user input text?

Tags: c++, windows

I working on a program that the user write text into a editbox, and then I create for him a txt file with his text inside.

How can I save his text from the editbox ?

I want to use it because I want to convert his text file to a binary file, but I my program can't take the data in the his txt file.

I can just use again the `GetWindowText` and the `GetWindowTextLength` functions, but there is a problem with it, he can remove the text from the editbox..

This part in my program is taking the text from the editbox, and then save and creats a txt file.

```
void write_file(char* path)
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(path, "w");

    int _size = GetWindowTextLength(filechoosed);
    char *data = new char[_size + 1];

    if (file) {
        GetWindowText(filechoosed, data, _size + 1);

        fwrite(data, _size + 1, 1, file);

        fclose(file);
    }

    return;
}

void save_file(HWND hWnd)
{
    char file_name[100];

    ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(OPENFILENAME));

    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
    ofn.hwndOwner = hWnd;
    ofn.lpstrFile = file_name;
    ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
    ofn.nMaxFile = 100;
    ofn.lpstrFilter = "txt File\0*.txt*\0";
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;

    GetSaveFileName(&ofn);

    write_file(ofn.lpstrFile);
}
```

I want to change my encryption way, my current way is just writing randomstring to the file, but there is no way to decrypt the file after it, so I want to save the text and then encrypt & decrypt it.

```
// Write & Save Encrypt File
void write_file_to_encrypt(char* path1)
{
    string str = randomString();

    FILE* file;

    file = fopen(path1, "w");

    if (file) {

        fwrite(str.c_str(), sizeof(char), str.size(), file);
        fclose(file);
    }

    return;
}

void save_file_to_encrypt(HWND hWnd1)
{
    OPENFILENAME ofn;

    char file_name[100];

    ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(OPENFILENAME));

    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
    ofn.hwndOwner = hWnd1;
    ofn.lpstrFile = file_name;
    ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
    ofn.nMaxFile = 100;
    ofn.lpstrFilter = "All Files\0*.*\0";
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;

    GetSaveFileName(&ofn);

    write_file_to_encrypt(ofn.lpstrFile);
}

// Decrypt
void write_file_to_decrypt(char* path2)
{
    FILE* file;
    file = fopen(path2, "w");

    int _size = GetWindowTextLength(filechoosed);
    char* data = new char[_size + 1];

    string str = data;

    if (file) {
        GetWindowText(filechoosed, data, _size + 1);

        fwrite(data, _size + 1, 1, file);

        fclose(file);
    }

    return;
}

void save_file_to_decrypt(HWND hWnd2)
{
    char file_name[100];

    ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(OPENFILENAME));

    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
    ofn.hwndOwner = hWnd2;
    ofn.lpstrFile = file_name;
    ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
    ofn.nMaxFile = 100;
    ofn.lpstrFilter = "txt File\0*.txt*\0";
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;

    GetSaveFileName(&ofn);

    write_file_to_decrypt(ofn.lpstrFile);
}
```

Update:
I made a global string variable called file_path, his value is data, the data the user write to the file, so next, i used this data to recover the text and then "decrypt" the file, when I decrypt two files at the same time, the value in the first file move to the second file.

So I check if write file is created, clear the string, but the value is still in the string, the problem is that if i create 1 txt file named "first" with a text "myFirst" and then create a file called "second" with a text "mySecond", and then encrypt, and when i want to decrypt the first one and then the second, the text in both of them is "myFirst", so i wanted to clear the string and start over when the user write to the file.

```
if (write_file) {
        str.clear();
        str = file_path;
    }

    FILE* file;
    file = fopen(path2, "w");

    if (file) {

        fwrite(str.c_str(), sizeof(char) , str.size(), file);

        fclose(file);
    }

    return;
```

**So, how can I save the text that the user entered and then use it for other things ?**

If you don't understand something || want more information, ask for it.

Comment: You already copied the user text into the buffer pointed to by `data` (which you promptly forget and leak)

Comment: @Botje Yes, but  I can't use it as a global variable.

Comment: Avoid identifiers starting with "_".

Comment: Did you just edit your question from "How can I write?" to "How can I encrypt what I successfully write?" Please do not change the core of a question after you got an answer (not even if the answer was lameantably given in a comment).

Comment: @Yunnosch This is a new question.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. Do not do that. It is considered a "moving target qustion" and not appreciated. It makes the comments (or worse an answer) look wrong and confused. Please consider returning this post back to what matches the comment by helpfully minded people and creating a new question which is less confusing. It seems that you got an upvote for an intersting question, but now it is a different question. Do you see how that is not how things can work here at StackOverflow?

Comment: If the initial quesiton was solved, consider making your own answer. Only that way the upvoted question becomes as helpful to others as the voter probably thought it would be. After editing, you have basically destroyed that good content. Actually your not really allowed to do that, if you read the small print of the terms of service of StackOverflow. You are not allowed to remove content, once you posted it here.

Comment: @Yunnosch This is a very new question, I have never asked for something similar to it in the past, I have just asked "How can I write a string into a FILE".

Comment: @Yunnosch And someone else already posted an answer to my recent question.

Comment: And then you got helpful comments and then you edited the question to start talking about encryption, which was not initially in this post and does not match the title.

Comment: To illustrate what I mean, have a look at the first version of this question, there is nothing in there which relates to encryption. The comments discuss that version. Then you introduce the idea of encryption.

Comment: @Yunnosch I will edit, Thanks.